# With Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ, is it possible to zip outbound and unzip inbound message

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

With Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ application, I am trying to compress (zip) the message before sending it by defining my own RabbitTemplate bean but it does not work.

Is there a way to do it by configuration (application.properties) or by another method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binder configuration automatically wires in a `GZipPostProcessor` on the sending side and a `DelegatingDecompressingPostProcessor` on the consumer side.

If you want to change it to a `ZipPostProcessor`, use a binder customizer to set it on the binder:

```java
/**
 * Set a {@link org.springframework.amqp.core.MessagePostProcessor} to compress
 * messages. Defaults to a
 * {@link org.springframework.amqp.support.postprocessor.GZipPostProcessor}.
 * @param compressingPostProcessor the post processor.
 */
public void setCompressingPostProcessor(
        MessagePostProcessor compressingPostProcessor) {
```

You have to set the producer binding property `compress` to `true` to enable compression on the sending side.

On the receiving side, the `DelegatingDecompressingPostProcessor` looks at the content encoding message property to determine whether decompression is needed and which decompressor to use.

**EDIT**

I've just noticed that the binder sets the compression level to 0 (NO_COMPRESSION). Use `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.compression-level=9` (BEST_COMPRESSION) or `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.compression-level=1` (BEST_SPEED).

See `java.util.zip.Deflater` for available levels.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/353

This only applies if using gzip.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.

Comment: I've just noticed that the binder sets the compression level to 0 (NO_COMPRESSION). Use `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.compression-level=9` (BEST_COMPRESSION) or `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.compression-level=1` (BEST_SPEED).